# Using jsdom with Readability in the context of Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, jsdom

I'm new to Expo and React Native and I am trying to use @mozilla/readability package in an app, to clean up a web page.

As far as i can tell, since I'm not running the readability code in the browser I need to create a DOM document on my own from the page source (cf. [Readability - Basic Usage](https://github.com/mozilla/readability#basic-usage)). It's also Readability that suggests [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) as a library for doing that.

However,

1. One can not use `jsdom` in Expo because it seems to expect dependencies part of the node standard library which are not available in React (e.g. `fs` with the error: `The package at "node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs". It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.`)
2. I can not use other libraries such as `htmlparser2`, `dom-parser`, and `parse5` because the DOM object they return does not seem to match the needs of Readability and Readability throws exceptions.

Does anybody have an idea of what can be done in such a situation? Thanks!